# What happens to other observables when rxjs.race() has been won?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Imagine we have couple Observables and we put them inside race() operator. When one of those will win others are cancelled or called 'complete' or what exactly? 
I haven't found any informations about it in official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a quick dig in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/ffb4b0b52f8f8402ddd354169be285c78fcf9988/CHANGELOG.md#700-alpha0-2019-09-18) shows that the rest of the observables will no longer be subscribed:

> race: race() will no longer subscribe to subsequent observables if a provided source synchronously errors or completes. This means side effects that might have occurred during subscription in those rare cases will no longer occur.